# tensorflow resize image by random factor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to resize an image by a factor during graph construction when the image size is unknown:

```
H, W, _ = img.get_shape()
scale = tf.random_uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=1.5, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None, name=None)
```

Out of these I need to magically compute a size which would translate to the following:

```
tf.image.resize_images(tf.expand_dims(img, 0), [H*scale, W*scale])
```

Which returns:

```
ValueError: 'size' must be a 1-D int32 Tensor
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mixing the python list `[H*scale, W*scale]` with tensors. By default, tensorflow will convert lists like this to tensorflow constants as appropriate. But in this case, your list contains tensors and you're ending up with a nested set of tensors that aren't 1D.

To avoid confusion in cases like this stop using python constructs such as the list and convert your height and width into tensorflow constructs explicitly and check their shape before proceeding.

```
x = tf.concat((scale*W, scale*H), axis=0)
print(x)
Tensor("concat_3:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Doing so shows us that we now have a 1D tensor as required. But it's float32 (at least it was in the simple test case I set up), so let's cast that to an int:

```
x = tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
```

Now you're ready to go

```
tf.image.resize_images(tf.expand_dims(img, 0), size=x)
```

No error should occur there.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. I had to add another thing though, so in case anyone else has the same problem, my way of obtaining H and W didn't work. Instead use: H = tf.shape(img)[0]
        W = tf.shape(img)[1]

Answer (score 5):

Your `scale` has shape `(1,)`, so `[H*scale, W*scale]` has shape `(1, 2)`. To fix it, just generate a scalar random instead of a 1-element vector:

```
scale = tf.random_uniform([], minval=1, maxval=1.5, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None, name=None)
```

Note the shape is an empty list, meaning you want a scalar.

In addition to that, you have to fix the data type of the `size` parameter, like this:

```
tf.image.resize_images(tf.expand_dims(img, 0), tf.cast([H*scale, W*scale], tf.int32))
```

Comment: Ah, great solution, for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to get a scalar out of `tf.random_uniform`. :)

Comment: Nice way of obtaining the random scalar. Thank you.